# C++ Delimiter in int array

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I have a question about picking a proper delimiter to split the int array. 
say, given

```
int[] a={2,3,4,5,6}
```

I want manually add some certain delimiter into the array so that I could split the int array into different groups, for example,

```
int[] b={2,?,4,5,?,6} => {2},{4,5},{6}
```

As above, what can I pick for the delimiter? And I guess maybe I can use some macro such as `MAX` or `MIN`. However, what if there's real number that equals to the boundary value?

I've been stuck at this problem for quite a while. Any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: And I am wishing for any solution that preserve the array as int type without converting to string...

Comment: Please clarify -- you question is related with [tag:c] or with [tag:c++]?

Comment: hmm..., may be instead of using delimiter you can create second array with group lengths: {1,2,1,0} and use these instead?

Comment: You have declared a as an array of int, therefore it can only contain int.  If you wish to declare some particular int as your delimiter -- and enforce the fact that it can appear only as a delimiter, you are certainly welcome to do so.   However you are probably trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in C++. There is no syntax for such logic, nor does it fit with the (generally) strongly typed nature of C++.

As an alternative, you can declare several arrays

```
int[] a= {2},
      b= {4,5},
      c= {6};
```

Declare an array of arrays

```
int[][] a={{2},{4,5},{6}};
```

Or create a function that will transform an array into groups based on your business logic.

```
int a={2,4,5,6};
int [][] groups = myMagicFunc(a);
```

Or just use a different data structure.

Comment: The rules of C++ perhaps? Did it compile for you?

Comment: @juanchopanza I haven't compiled it, but now that I look at it, you would be right. Was too lazy to put array sizes :)

Comment: if you do `vector<vector<int>> a={{2},{4,5},{6}};`, it would work, and then you can introduce the OP to c++ stl as well!

Comment: Hi Ben,what does OP mean?

Comment: You shouldn't really suggest code that isn't even C++.

Comment: @ShirleyFeng Note that none of this is really valid C++.